# Active Record Observer not firing in console/seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

I have observers set up to award badges on model changes.
It works when I'm using the view, but I doesn't seem to fire when I do something like :
Photo.create(:user_id => user.id, :file => file) from the console or from the seed file.

Any idea ?

```
class ExplorerObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :photo

  def after_save(photo)
    user = photo.user
    Explorer.award_achievements_for(user) unless photo.new_record?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake, it was a silly issue, but for the archive, here is my answer :

If you have multiple observers, dont put multiple lines like that

```
config.active_record.observers = :popular_observer
config.active_record.observers = :explorer_observer
```

instead chain your observers, my previous code was overwriting the observers with the last one !

```
config.active_record.observers = :popular_observer, :explorer_observer
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to put it in `config/application.rb`, inside your `Application` class?

```
config.active_record.observers = :photo_observer
```

Comment: No, I had : config.active_record.observers = :explorer_observer, which works because the rules are working in the view.